# How should I deal with declined card with Hotels.com?

Tags: hotels, payment-cards, payment

I reserved a hotel room using Hotels.com, and the card got declined due to the exceeded limit. They were able to charge me part of the bill (one night out of the several), however.

I increased the card limit, and now the hotel can charge me the rest of the bill. However, I am having a problem in communicating with them, as the staffs are not particularly proficient in English and not answering my e-mails promptly.

What should I try, in this situation?

The payment request came from the hotel, not from Hotels.com (or at least that's what the bank says). Also, the reservation is not refundable.

Comment: Did you originally choose to pay via hotels.com or pay at the hotel? (Though some hotels only have the option of paying at the hotel.)

Comment: @MichaelHampton I do not remember it, but apprantly the hotel is charging me directly (that's what a Hotels.com staff and the bank says).

Comment: I've just had two bookings declined where I filled in my credit card details on Hotels.com in the evening, and during the following day, two transactions from the two different hotels got declined and I got emails direct from the hotel in French.
What concerns me is that I thought I was securely entering my credit card details with Hotels.com, but the transaction was with the hotel. Perhaps there's some clever tech behind the scenes keeping this secure, but it's a bit concerning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask the booking site to forward a mail for you, translated into the language the site uses to communicate with the hotel.
It might be best to find someone to translate for you. If that fails write in English and add a computer translation in the local language for the hotel.

Keep the message short and ask for a reply.